# Flutter Web Space button not working on keyboard on IOS

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-web

I have a Flutter Web app deployed on Firebase.

On chrome and safari everything is fine when on an Android

But on IOS,  the space button does nothing when inputting text in a TextField.

Tried dev, stable and master channel

Even while using this sample code for a CupertinoTextField it has the issue with space button on IOS not working on Flutter Web

https://gallery.flutter.dev/#/demo/cupertino-text-field

```
C:\Users\Takabayashi\dpp_web>flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel master, 2.3.0-13.0.pre.73, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.985], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 4.2.0)
[√] VS Code (version 1.56.2)
[√] Connected device (2 available)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: Hi @Rhetta Hovdal! If you could add some more information to your post it would be really helpful. Things to include would be some example code of what you're doing, things you've tried, and any bugs or log messages you're getting.

Comment: Hello, I updated the post. And tried it with just the CupertinoTextField example from the flutter website.  Same issue with space not working on IOS

Comment: I found an answer to the same [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68658277/13781490)