# Space bar not working for a TextField in iPhone(Safari as well as Chrome) in Flutter Webapp

Tags: ios, flutter, safari, flutter-web

I have a Flutter Web app deployed on Firebase.

On AndroidPhone/Laptop/Macbook everything is working fine whether it may be on Safari or Chrome.

But on iOS, the space button does nothing when inputting text in a TextField.

The issue is pretty similar to [Flutter #79082](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/79082), but this time it's on iPhone(iOS) only!

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel master, 2.3.0-13.0.pre.73, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.985], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 4.2.0)
[√] VS Code (version 1.56.2)
[√] Connected device (2 available)

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Manually setting keyboard shortcut for Space key worked for me!

In your main.dart paste the following line of code inside MaterialApp

```
shortcuts: {
    LogicalKeySet(LogicalKeyboardKey.space): ActivateIntent(),
 },
```

Your main.dart should look like:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return MaterialApp(
   shortcuts: {
     LogicalKeySet(LogicalKeyboardKey.space): ActivateIntent(),
   },
   title: 'title of your app',
   //....
 );
}
```